# How do you capture the id of a record when it is created?

Tags: google-app-maker

So I have a script, that among other things, does this:

widget.datasource.createItem();

How do I capture the ID of the item?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/client#DataSource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried using the link provided by @Morfinismo and it worked. Try with

```
datasource.createItem(function(record) {

var key = record._key;

     alert("Created new record. Id: " + key);

   });
```

here https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/client#Record you will find the information about the property "._key" which will be the id in this case for your question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is my best bet:

```
datasource.createItem(function(record) {
     alert("Created new record. Name was: " + record.name);
   });
```